# how to automatically generate tags from a article, base on a tag list?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, tags

when user write a article, i wanna automatically generate tags from user writes base on a existing tag list.

for example, i got a list like:

Manhattan
Brooklyn
Queens
....

if user write a article which contains these key words, it will come to the tags.

like user have title :"Today i skated in Manhattan", then Manhattan should be include tags.

i had considered foreach the tag list, but it is very slow if the tag list come to a big size.

Do you guys have any solutions to automatically generate tags? or have any idea to implement this problem ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the number of tags you have, a trie is likely to work well in this situation. With a trie, you build a tree data structure of the prefixes of your tags. For example, if you had tags like "A", "to", "tea", "ted", "ten", "i", "in", and "inn" then you would build the following "prefix tree":

```
+ - i - + i + - n - + in + - n - + inn +
  - A - + A +
  - t - + t + - o - + to +
              - e - + te + - n - + ten +
                           - a - + tea +
                           - d - + ted +
```

In this tree, the "- character -" indicates an edge and "+ string +" indicates a node. Once you've built this trie, I imagine the following algorithm:

```
TrieNode root = rootOfTrie;
TrieNode current = root;

while (still typing)
{
   switch (key pressed)
   {
      case letter:

         if (current == null)
            break;

         bool found = false;

         foreach (successor trie edge)
         {
            if (edge.Letter == letter)
            {
               current = sucessor edge.node;
               found = true;
               break;
            }
         }

         if (!found)
            current = null;

         break;

      case whitespace:

         if (current != root && current != null && trie node is tag)
            suggest node current as tag;

         current = root;
         break;

      case backspace:

         // You may want to handle this case by back-tracking in the trie.

         current = null;
         break;

      default:

         current = null;
         break;
   }
}
```

Read more trie data structures at Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

Answer (score 0):

Idea - client + server side solution:

You probably have an heading textfield and then another input (textarea) with body of article. You need an event which is fired when users leaves heading input (or enters textarea input). Then you can grab text from textarea and compare it with list of available tags (this could be quite slow if you have hundreds of tags).

How to compare: Let's say, that at server side, you generated list of available tags and you did set that list as a content of some hidden field at page. Then at client side, you can read content of that hidden field and load list of tags to some list var. (Or you can use ajax for this.. depends on your skills). Now you have list of available tags and one sentence (title of article). You can split that sentence and pick each word longer than 2 chars (for example) and then check, if that list of tags contains given word (for each word that you got from splitting).

Pseudocode for this:

```
foreach(string word in titleSplit)
{
    if (listOfTags.contains(word))
    {
        // You have matching word-tag.
        // Add it's text into your tags element, or to some collection
        // which will be processed later on.
        tags.add(word);
    }
}
```

I would need more specific context to provide more specific answer (idea) :)

Comment: Hi Dampe, thanks for your quick response, the problem is i have thousands of tags, if foreach all the tags, then it will like you said, very slow.

Comment: Ah, then this is out of my league I guess :X I don't know how to do this kind of optimized search.

Comment: if your tag list is in memory, a hashtable would be fast ... on the other hand ... an indexed table in a database could do this job aswell ...

Answer (score 0):

Use a HashSet to store your tags.

Below article for reference:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/6a994e32-efc3-4f4b-8b60-ab357d5c1020/